# Images not displaying in correct order for configurable product in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, product-images

The images for the configurable product dont appear in proper order as in backend.
See https://prnt.sc/128ldmw and https://prnt.sc/128leye
I want to display them in the same order as they are in the backend.
I am using magento 2.3.3 instance.

Comment: If it is what i think it could be because the images were pushed trough an api and the images does not have an attribute order setted correctly so they just appear in random order in the backend and the frontend. Try to resave the products images to force the creation of an image order to see if the position change after on the frontend.

Comment: They are added manually from backend . Not by API. Do u have any solution for this?